# freeRADIUS server confiuration for 802.1x

Tags: freeradius, wifi

I want to configure freeRADIUS server as a authentication server for enterprise WLAN testing. I'm new to freeRADIUS server configuration. please give me the step by step or any link for installation and configuration

Thanks,
Devaa

Answer (score 3):

First we’ll need a place to work, so I created a directory:

```
mkdir /usr/src/freeradius && cd /usr/src/freeradius
```

Next we need to fetch our source and get any dependencies, so update your sources and enter the following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get build-dep freeradius
apt-get install libssl-dev fakeroot
apt-get source freeradius
```

This should have downloaded the FreeRADIUS source code for us, so now we’ll have to make a few changes to tell our compiler to build it with the EAP modules we’ll be using. First edit `/usr/src/freeradius/freeradius-1.1.3/debian/control` and remove `libssl-dev` from `Build-Conflicts`: and add it to the end of `Build-Depends: line`. Your file should look like this:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 5), libltdl3-dev, libpam0g-dev, libmysqlclient15-dev | libmysqlclient-dev, libgdbm-dev, libldap2-dev, libsasl2-dev, libiodbc2-dev, libkrb5-dev, snmp, autotools-dev, dpatch (>= 2), libperl-dev, libtool, dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.19), libssl-dev
Build-Conflicts:
```

Next you’ll need to add descriptions for your EAP modules, so enter the following at the end of the file:

```
Package: freeradius-eaptls
Architecture: any
Depends: freeradius (= ${binary:Version}), ${shlibs:Depends}
Description: eap-tls module for FreeRADIUS server
Debian will not provide a binary version of the rlm_eap_tls.so library. This
module is required if you want to use EAP/TLS authentication, commonly used
for WiFi access points.

Package: freeradius-eappeap
Architecture: any
Depends: freeradius (= ${binary:Version}), ${shlibs:Depends}
Description: eap-peap module for FreeRADIUS server
Debian will not provide a binary version of the rlm_eap_peap.so library. This
module is required if you want to use EAP/PEAP authentication, commonly used
for WiFi access points.
```

Save and exit this file.

Next we’ll edit `/usr/src/freeradius/freeradius-1.1.3/debian/rules`. Find and comment our the “buildssl=” and “moduleslist=-“ lines and add the following lines:

```
buildssl=–without-rlm_otp –without-rlm_sql_postgresql –without-snmp
modulelist=krb5 ldap sql_mysql sql_iodbc eap_peap eap_tls
```

Save and exit.

Now enter the following commands:

```
echo “usr/lib/freeradius/rlm_eap_tls*.so” >/usr/src/freeradius/freeradius-1.1.3/debian/freeradius-eaptls.install
echo “usr/lib/freeradius/rlm_eap_peap*.so” > /usr/src/freeradius/freeradius-1.1.3/debian/freeradius-eappeap.install
```

Next let’s create `/usr/src/freeradius/freeradius-1.1.3/debian/freeradius-eaptls.postinst` and enter the following:

```
#! /bin/sh

set -e

case "$1" in
 configure)
       if [ -x "`which invoke-rc.d 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
         invoke-rc.d freeradius restart
       else
         /etc/init.d/freeradius restart
       fi
       ;;
 abort-upgrade)
       ;;
 abort-remove)
       ;;
 abort-deconfigure)
       ;;
esac

#DEBHELPER#
```

Now we’ll create `/usr/src/freeradius/freeradius-1.1.3/debian/freeradius-eappeap.postinst` and add the following to it:

```
#! /bin/sh

set -e

case "$1" in
 configure)
       if [ -x "`which invoke-rc.d 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
         invoke-rc.d freeradius reload
       else
         /etc/init.d/freeradius reload
       fi
       ;;
 abort-upgrade)
       ;;
 abort-remove)
       ;;
 abort-deconfigure)
       ;;
esac

#DEBHELPER#
```

Now that the hard part is finished let’s compile our deb packages. Enter the following command:

```
cd /usr/src/freeradius/freeradius-1.1.3/
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -us
```

If all went well you should now have several of .deb packages in `/usr/src/freradius`, so let’s install them by entering the following:

```
dpkg -i freeradius_1.1.3-3_i386.deb
dpkg -i freeradius-eaptls_1.1.3-3_i386.deb
dpkg -i freeradius-eappeap_1.1.3-3_i386.deb
```

Check to see if FreeRADIUS compiled and installed correctly by issues the following command:

```
ps aux | grep freeradius

And you should see something similar to this:

freerad 29998 0.0 0.8 44620 2224 ? Ssl 00:55 0:00 /usr/sbin/freeradius
```

If not start FreeRADIUS in debug mode as root and look for any clues to why things are not working properly:

```
freeradius –X
```

Also check `/usr/lib/freeradius` and ensure that the `rlm_eap_peap-1.1.3.so` and `rlm_eap_tls-1.1.3.so` modules exist.

Now to configure FreeRADIUS

First we’ll edit `/etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf`

> NOTE: When editing the configuration files be sure that every open bracket ({) has a corresponding ending bracket (}) or you will break FreeRADIUS!

Find the mschap stanza under MODULES and configure it with the following parameters:

```
mschap {
                authtype = MS-CHAP
                use_mppe = yes
                require_encryption = yes
                require_strong = yes
 }
```

Next verify the authorize stanza includes these parameters:

```
preprocess
mschap
suffix
eap
files
```

Now verify that the authenticate stanza is configured like this:

```
authenticate {
    #  MSCHAP authentication.   
    Auth-Type MS-CHAP {
mschap
}
#  Allow EAP authentication.
         eap
}
```

Now we have to add a client to the `clients.conf`. By client we mean an authenticator such as an access point (AP) or a wireless controller. For this example we’ll use my Juniper SSG5’s address of `192.168.44.129`. Add the following stanza to the `clients.conf`:

```
client  192.168.44.129 {
    secret = test123
    shortname = Juniper
}
```

Next we’ll configure our server to support PEAP by editing `/etc/freeradius/eap.conf`.

First change the `default_eap_type` in the eap stanza to look like this:

```
default_eap_type = peap
```

Because PEAP needs to support our example certificates uncomment the tls stanza as well as the following parameters.

```
tls {
private_key_password = whatever
private_key_file = ${raddbdir}/certs/cert-srv.pem
certificate_file = ${raddbdir}/certs/cert-srv.pem
CA_file = ${raddbdir}/certs/demoCA/cacert.pem
dh_file = ${raddbdir}/certs/dh
random_file = ${raddbdir}/certs/random
}
```

Next find and uncomment the peap stanza and the following parameter:

```
default_eap_type = mschapv2
```

Now add a test user in the `/etc/freeradius/users` file so we can test the system. Add the following:

```
“tobias” User-Password == “password123”

Restart FreeRADIUS with the following command:

/etc/init.d/freeradius restart
```

Now if you’ve done everything correctly you should be able to authenticate with your test user with the following command:

```
radtest tobias password123 localhost 0 testing123
```

You should see:

```
ending Access-Request of id 170 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
    User-Name = "tobias"
    User-Password = "password123"
    NAS-IP-Address = 255.255.255.255
    NAS-Port = 0
rad_recv: Access-Accept packet from host 127.0.0.1:1812, id=170, length=20
```

At this point everything should be working, although you would have to export your CA’s certificate to your PEAP clients so they would trust the server certificate being used by FreeRADIUS. The certificates we are currently using are there only to test with and should not be used for production. Next I’ll explain how to setup your own certificate authority (CA) and create your own certificates.

First we’ll need to install OpenSSL and since we’ll need to generate some complex passwords we’ll also install PWGen the password generator.

```
apt-get install openssl pwgen
```

OpenSSL uses a defaults file, `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`, that we’ll backup and edit to save us some time when we start generating our certs.

```
cp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.bak
```

Now edit `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and find this line:

```
dir =./demoCA
```

and change to:

```
dir =/etc/freeradius/eap/eapCA
```

This is the location were I’ll be creating the new CA. You might want to look through the rest of the file and edit the defaults to your environment. Here are some of the changes that I made to my `openssl.cnf`.

```
-countryName_default = AU
+countryName_default = US

-stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State
+stateOrProvinceName_default = Oregon

+localityName_default = Portland

-0.organizationName_default = Widget ltd
+0.organizationName_default = Fat of the LAN
```

Now create and change to the directory that all of our certificates and CA will exist:

```
mkdir /etc/freeradius/eap && cd /etc/freeradius/eap
```

We will use one of OpenSSL’s included scripts to generate our CA, but you’ll want to customize it a bit before we use it so we’ll make a copy of it in our certificate directory.

```
cp /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl /etc/freeradius/eap
```

Next we have to edit CA.pl to tell it where to create our CA. Open it and change the following line:

```
CATOP=./demoCA
```

to:

```
CATOP=/etc/freeradius/eap/eapCA
```

Your CA is at the heart of your certificate infrastructure so it is important to protect it once you’ve generated it as well as use a strong password for it. I’ll generate a nice random 25 character password with pwgen. Be sure to record this password as you’ll need it each time you sign a certificate.

```
pwgen 25 1
aem5xahheethohP5Woh5Eb3ph
```

Now let’s run the script from within the `/etc/freeradius/eap` directory.

```
cd /etc/freeradius/eap
./CA.pl –newca
```

Answer all of the questions based on your environment and use the password you just created when prompted. When the script finishes you’ll have your own CA in `/etc/freeradius/eap/eapCA`. The next thing we need to do is create a server certificate for FreeRADIUS and sign it with our new CA.

```
./CA.pl –newreq-nodes
```

We should now have a new key pair as well as a signing request ready to send to our CA.

A quick note on compatibility. If you plan to use any of these certificates on Windows clients you’ll need to add XP extensions to the certificates you generate. The xpextensions file is included with Debian’s FreeRADIUS packages and I’ll include it in the appendix for our non-Debian readers. Just make a copy of it in our certificate directory.

```
cp /usr/share/doc/freeradius/examples/xpextensions /etc/freeradius/eap
```

Now let’s use our CA key to sign the FreeRADIUS’ certificate request, entering the CA’s password when prompted:

```
./CA.pl –sign (Optionally add -extensions xpserver_ext -extfile /etc/freeradius/eap/xpextensions)
```

Now that all of the certificates we need are generated, we need to create a couple of files needed for keying material and tell FreeRADIUS to use the new certs. To create the dh and random files, issue the following command:

```
openssl dhparam -check -text -5 512 -out dh
dd if=/dev/urandom of=random count=2
chmod 640 random newcert.pem newkey.pem newreq.pem dh
```

Now open your `/etc/freeradius/eap.conf` file, find the tls stanza, and change to reflect the new certificates we created.

```
private_key_file = /etc/freeradius/eap/newkey.pem
certificate_file = /etc/freeradius/eap/newcert.pem
CA_file = /etc/freeradius/eap/eapCA/cacert.pem
dh_file = /etc/freeradius/eap/dh
random_file = /etc/freeradius/eap/random
```

And while we’re at it, uncomment the following lines:

```
fragment_size = 1024
include_length = yes
```

Restart FreeRADIUS and copy your CA’s certificate (`/etc/freeradius/eap/eapCA/cacert.pem`) to your clients. Configure your clients’ supplicant for your new PEAP enabled SSID, configure your AP to use 802.1x and your new FreeRADIUS server and you’re good to go!

If you are looking for more information on RADIUS, check out this book. It’s been extremely helpful thus far.

Comment: "check out this book" - is it some link supposed to follow this? Looks like you have forgotten to add it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is so broad. It really depends on what you want to do, where your authentication data (e.g. users/passwords) is stored, what type of EAP methods you are going to use, etc.

However, the default FreeRADIUS configuration will work pretty well for most testing with minimal changes.

Start by editing the `raddb/users` file and add a new user to the top. The form should be like

```
username    Cleartext-Password := "password"
```

Then you can use `radtest` or `eapol_test` to check to see if this is working.

When that works, you can edit the `clients.conf` file to add your wireless AP or controller.

You should then be able to connect from the wireless network.

However, this can be quite complicated and there are lots of things to go wrong along the way, so don't be discouraged if it doesn't work first time.

**Always** run the server with debugging on (`radiusd -X`) when testing, and read all the output. It will show you where things are failing.

There is a lot of information on the [FreeRADIUS wiki](http://wiki.freeradius.org/), for example start with the [Basic configuration HOWTO](http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Basic-configuration-HOWTO). There is also lots of good tutorial advice on [Alan Dekok's page](http://deployingradius.com/documents/configuration/setup.html). Note that for wireless you do need to configure EAP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I brought up free radius server. Its says that ready to process request.

Then how to connect using any EAP method. Now I want my supplicant to connect it to my freeradius server using WPA2-enterprise security.

Please help me to connect my supplicant to radius server

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step link that I used for my freeradius installation. 
[Freeradius 3 Ubuntu tutorial](https://draculaservers.com/tutorials/freeradius-ubuntu-18-04-mysql/)

If you're still having issues, get a vps that comes with radius installed